# Generating buy/sell signals in pairs trading

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, pairs-trading

I'm reading a quantitative trading book"Quantitative Trading with R" by Harry Georgakopoulos.
In the pairs trading section, there's an example that creates the spread and generate buy/sell signals.

y and x are the price changes of two correlated stocks.

```
data$spread <- y - hedge_ratio*x
threshold <- sd(data$spread, na.rm = TRUE)
# Generate sell and buy signals
buys <- ifelse(data_out$spread > threshold, 1, 0)
sells <- ifelse(data_out$spread < -threshold, -1, 0)
```

I don't understand why do we buy the spread if spread>threshold... In my opinion, if spread>threshold means it is valuable, so we should sell it but in the example, the spread is bought.

Thanks!

Comment: This is basically the same question.  There are a few answers that may help clarify for you. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47277/pair-trading-short-long-the-spread/47279#47279

Answer (score 1):

It's a mean reversion play. So if the spread > then the threshold you are betting the spread reverts back. The higher the threshold the fewer amount of times you are betting. I would take a look at how many pairs you are generating with the volatility.